# Chamando uma função, após renderização de um componente em React.js

Tags: javascript, react

Estou fazendo um jogo da velha em React.js que utiliza o algoritmo Minimax para produzir as jogadas da IA. Esse algoritmo, pelo que vi, está demorando entre 600ms ~ 1000ms para retornar uma jogada nos primeiros estágios do jogo. Esse tempo não seria problema se não fosse pelo fato de que eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que a jogada da IA aconteça depois do click handler que ocorre quando o jogador humano clica em um quadrado para fazer sua jogada. Resultando em o usuário clicando no quadrado e o browser "travando" até o algoritmo terminar.

**Board.js**

```
class Board extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state ={
        whosTurn: this.props.playerSymbol,
        gameState: new GameState(Array(9).fill(null))
      }
    }

    handleSquareClick(index){
      let board = this.state.gameState.board;

      if(board[index] === null){
        board[index] = this.state.whosTurn;
        this.setState({
          whosTurn: Math.abs(this.state.whosTurn - 1),
          gameState: new GameState(board)
        });
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      if(this.state.whosTurn !== this.props.playerSymbol){
        // Aqui é a função que "trava" minha execução
        let newGameState = this.state.gameState.minimax();
        this.setState({
          gameState: newGameState
        });
      }
    }

    render(){
      // Renderiza o jogo de acordo com o this.state.gameState
    }
}
```

Não sei muito de React ainda, mas pelo que eu li na documentação, o método `componentDidUpdate()` vem depois do `render()` no ciclo de vida do componente, sendo assim, o click do jogador humano não deveria já ter sido renderizado?

Um exemplo +/- visual:

**Vez do jogador humano**

[image: Vez do jogador humano]

**Quando ele clica, um for-loop é acionado para simular o algoritmo pensando. Perceba que o símbolo dele não foi renderizado ainda**

[image: Thinking]

**Ao terminar o loop o simbolo finalmente é renderizado. E vem aquele warning de graça ainda**

[image: Done]

Agradeço qualquer ajuda possível.

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/1ve7gc8e/ ? Não acho boa ideia usares o `componentDidUpdate` para fazer nova chamada do algoritmo. Seria melhor uma callback do `setState`, mas com um jsFidddle seria melhor para perceber como tens agora.

Comment: Olá sérgio, estou tendo dificuldades em botar nesse jsFiddle que você passou, mas [aqui](https://github.com/matheuscorreia/tictactoe) está o repositório do projeto. Vou pesquisar sobre isso de callback no setState, e aplicarei. Obrigado